# wxPython minimal size of Frame with a Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

wxpython 2.8.11.0, python 2.7

If i put some `Sizer` with some controls directly into a `Frame` like

```
import wx

app=wx.App()

frm = wx.Frame(None, title='title')

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(frm))
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(frm))

frm.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
frm.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

the `Frame` will automagically have a correct minimum size to contain the `Sizer` and it is not possible to make it smaller.
If there is a `Panel` in between (as needed for tabbing between controls) this does not work, the window can be made too small.

```
import wx

app=wx.App()

frm = wx.Frame(None, title='title')
pan = wx.Panel(frm)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(pan))
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(pan))

pan.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
frm.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Additionally `frm.Fit()` and `frm.SetMinSize(frm.GetEffectiveMinSize())` are required to get the same behavior. Full Code:

```
import wx

app=wx.App()

frm = wx.Frame(None, title='title')
pan = wx.Panel(frm)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(pan))
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(pan))

pan.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
frm.Fit()
frm.SetMinSize(frm.GetEffectiveMinSize())
frm.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

I am okay with `frm.Fit()`, but i dislike `frm.SetMinSize(frm.GetEffectiveMinSize())`. Isn't there a better solution so that the `Frame` automatically considers the minimum size of the `Panel` just like with the `Sizer` before? I'm considered with what happens if the `EffectiveMinSize` changes after another control is added to the sizer.

**Edit:** 
Apparently

```
panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
frm.Fit()
frm.SetMinSize(frm.GetEffectiveMinSize())
```

should be replaced by

```
panel.SetSizer(sizer)
sizer.SetSizeHints(frm)
```

which looks somewhat cleaner. So in total this looks like

```
import wx

app=wx.App()

frm = wx.Frame(None, title='title')
pan = wx.Panel(frm)

sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(pan))
sizer.Add(wx.SpinCtrl(pan))

pan.SetSizer(sizer)
sizer.SetSizeHints(frm)
frm.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Is this the preferred way to do this?

If widgets are added later on even the first approach with the `Sizer` directly on the `Frame` doesn't get it right without intervention, so i think that is a totally different question.

Comment: If you are using wxpython >=3, `wx.Frame.SetMinSize` is preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most elegant way (IMHO) is given in phineas' answer. It is slightly inefficient to have an extra otherwise unneeded sizer but I don't think it can really be noticeable.

Some people do call `SetSizeHints()` manually, as in your last example, and this works as well and might be more clear (whenever I use an extra sizer I feel the need to leave a comment explaining why it shouldn't be removed).

Unfortunately there is no better way and I am not sure if we can even add one because you need to do something with all of the panel, the sizer and the frame and this means that you can't do it with a single method call without passing unrelated parameters to it. I.e. we could have something like

```
panel.SetSizerAndFitParent(sizer, frame);
```

but it's not really clear whether this would be better.

Comment: thank you for the comment @VZ, as i said in my other comment @phineas solution with an extra `Sizer` works.  I find adding another Object in between a bit less elegant than just an extra method call to `SetSizeHints()`, so i think i will stick to `SetSizeHints()`.

Answer (score 2):

What about introducing a sizer that manages the frame content (e.g. the panel)? Since you didn't include a minimal example, I haven't tested it yet.

```
frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
frameSizer.Add(panel)
frm.SetSizerAndFit(frameSizer)
```

Comment: Hello @phineas,

i have added minimal examples to my question. I also tried your solution and it works just like calling `SetSizeHints()`, but i find it a bit unelegant to have this extra `Sizer` around.

Comment: Good efforts. You're right, the additional sizer makes much more sense if you're going to add more than one panel.