# wxPython ScrolledPanel not resizing in dialog

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

To start off, I'm using wxPython 2.8.12.1.

I'm trying to create a settings dialog, where a user can view and then edit certain settings. Atm I have the settings in a scrolled panel and then I hope to add the panel to my dialog, with "Save" and "Cancel" buttons at the bottom of the dialog. I can vaguely get what I need, but the scrolled panel starts off incredibly small (does not even show one whole vertical line of text at a time), and it does not resize with the dialog. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class SettingsDialog(wx.Dialog):    
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the dialog"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Settings', size=(100,100),
                           style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # Add Settings Panel
        self.panel = SettingsPanel(self)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        # Add Save/Cancel Buttons
        self.createWidgets()
        # Set sizer and window size
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self)

    def createWidgets(self):
        """Create and layout the widgets in the dialog"""
        btnSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()

        saveBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, label="Save")
        saveBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSave)
        btnSizer.AddButton(saveBtn)

        cancelBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        btnSizer.AddButton(cancelBtn)
        btnSizer.Realize()

        self.mainSizer.Add(btnSizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5)

    def OnSave(self, event):
        pass

class SettingsPanel(scrolled.ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.SetupScrolling()

    def createWidgets(self):
        """Create and layout the widgets in the panel"""
        settingsSizer = wx.GridSizer(rows=0, cols=2, hgap=5, vgap=0)

        names = #List of names grabbed from elsewhere
        values = #List of values grabbed from elsewhere
        name_value_dict = zip(names, values)

        for name, value in name_value_dict:
            lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=''.join([name,':']))
            settingsSizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=value, name="Name")
            settingsSizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.mainSizer.Add(settingsSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        dlg = SettingsDialog()
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Any help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code with wxPython version 3.0 and it looks as you want. It will work with version 2.8 as well. Let me explain what you should do.

1. Make your dialog's size bigger. It is not enough to show all the widgets. `wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Settings', size=(300, 300), ...`
2. Add a `size` argument for your `ScrolledPanel` like this `scrolled.ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(200, 200))`

That's all. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay thanks. I've yet to take a closer look, but I wasn't too worried about setting the sizes when initializing. I was hoping sizer.Fit(parent) would take care of that.

Comment: So it looks like setting the size was the main issue. Is there an easy way to automate this in case the settings change size? Is that even good practice, or is it better to have a default size that looks okay? With what I had before, I was hoping the panel would be fit to include all the widgets, and then the dialog would be fit to include the panel and the buttons.

Comment: There are some ways, this post discusses it http://stackoverflow.com/q/12607460/5303401